# Extracting substring after comma

Tags: string, substring, stata

I have a variable in Stata called `place` with entries that look like `"Wichita, Kansas"`.

I want to split this variable into a `city` and `state` variable. The state always comes after a comma and a space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
input str20(place)
"Wichita, Kansas"
"Salt Lake City, Utah"
"Buffalo, New York"
end

split place, p(",")

list

     +---------------------------------------------------+
     |                place           place1      place2 |
     |---------------------------------------------------|
  1. |      Wichita, Kansas          Wichita      Kansas |
  2. | Salt Lake City, Utah   Salt Lake City        Utah |
  3. |    Buffalo, New York          Buffalo    New York |
     +---------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Wonderful! Just what I needed. I used , p(" ,") to account for the space. Thank you!

Comment: This is exactly what is needed, but people with similar questions might note the string functions `strpos()` to find the first occurrence of a character in a string (here of a comma) and `substr()` to extract a substring, which are doing much of the work inside the command `split`.

Comment: Note that `split` trims leading and trailing spaces aggressively and by design -- unless you specify otherwise. (Original code author speaking here.)